# How to drag an undecorated window in Qt

Tags: c++, qt

I have undecorated my window as follows:

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QWidget(parent, Qt::FramelessWindowHint | Qt::WindowSystemMenuHint)
{}
```

How can I make it draggable?

Comment: you can generate drag event manually and react on it in 

virtual void 
dragEnterEvent(QDragEnterEvent *event);
virtual void 
dragLeaveEvent(QDragLeaveEvent *event)
virtual void 
dragMoveEvent(QDragMoveEvent *event);
virtual void 
dropEvent(QDropEvent *event);
virtual void 
enterEvent(QEvent *event);

for areas on which you want drag window

Answer (score 3):

Since you removed the window decoration and thus any access point the windowing system would have for providing movement, you'll have to implement it yourself.

You can either reimplement the window's mouse event handlers, or use an event filter on the window object.

See `QWidget::mousePressEvent()`, `QWidget::mouseMoveEvent()`, `QWidget::mouseReleaseEvent()` and `QObject::eventFilter()` respectively.

And `QWidget::move()` for the actual movement of course.

Since you already have a derived class, implementing the event handlers is probably the more straight forward approach.

Answer (score 1):

Since Qt 5.15, there is [`QWindow::startSystemMode`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwindow.html#startSystemMove) for exactly this use-case.

Here is an example snippet for a widget that triggers the system move handling for its window, when it is left-clicked:

```cpp
void WindowMoveWidget::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
{
    if (event->button() == Qt::LeftButton) {
        window()->windowHandle()->startSystemMove();
        return;
    }

    return QWidget::mousePressEvent(event);
}
```

For more information see the respective [blog post](https://www.qt.io/blog/custom-window-decorations).

Note that the function returns whether the operation is supported by the system, so you  may want to check its return value and implement a fallback based on `QWidget::move`.